# Intercept HTTP request via Internet Explorer extension

Tags: javascript, http, internet-explorer

I need your help.
I'm developing an IE extension and it must get information about every outcome HTTP request done from the IE. Is it possible?
For example, in Chrome it can be achieved with `chrome.webRequest`, in Firefox - with `httpObserver`, but I have not found a way to do it in IE extension.
Is it possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
HttpListener
```

There is more to read about it on MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener(v=vs.110).aspx